# Using web socket in angular 6

Tags: angular, websocket, angular6

I am trying to get fetch data from a web socket. I am initializing websocket object as globally.

```
socket =new WebSocket('ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/socket');
```

on ngOnInit I am opening the connection with :

```
this.socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log("websocket is open now");
  }
```

Now I need to send the message using a function which I am triggering from UI and the reply from websocket should store the message in a global variable.

```
sampleFunction(val) {
    this.socket.send(val);
    this.socket.onmessage=function(event){
      console.log("got message");
      this.dummy=event.data;
    }.bind(this)
  }
```

So on page load it is getting connected, but when I trigger the function the message is not going and thus I am not getting any response back

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: "global " = angular service

Answer (score 1):

I'm using rxjs that comes with Angular and its webSocket method.

```
import {webSocket} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
socket = webSocket(`${environment.serviceWebSockets}/api`);
constructor(){
    // now you can subscribe to messages wherever in your code
    this.socket.subscribe(message => {
        console.log(message); // or just use it directly
    }, error => {
        console.error(error); // handle errors
    });
}
```

to send data over this webSocket:

```
socket.next(JSON.stringify({some:"data"}));
```

for connecting use:

```
socket.subscribe();
```

for disconnecting:

```
socket.complete();
```

more info on https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket

Comment: Can you please share documentation of implementation ? Which will show how to open connection and then sending some data to ws server.

Comment: Where to open and close the connection ? And what is the messages varaible for ?

Comment: You don't need messages and errors variables, I fixed the post, you can just handle message and error variables when you receive them in subscribe. You get message when server sends something, and you send to server with next.

Comment: One more problem I am facing, I am sending a variable to websocket but its value if recieved with double quotes, due to which I am not able to run some logic on websocket server end.

Comment: You probably have to parse the data, use JSON.parse or try sending a plain object

Comment: As I have posted in my question , I need to open ws on ngonit that will be one time with webSocket.subscribe(). Now there is function with a parameter which is getting passed from front end , that parameter need to sent to ws and it send some result. In the function I am using this.webScoket.next(param) and after that this.webSocket.subscribe to get the result. But I am not getting it. I browser networks tab in dev too I can see data but in console its not printing (which statement I have written inside subscribe part.

Comment: You need to subscribe before sending the data, try setting the subscribe line before next line

Comment: I used subscribe before then .next but still its not executing. The request goes and result is coming i can see in network tab of dev tools. But its not coming in subscribe.  this.socket.subscribe(
      (msg) => console.log('message received: ' + msg),
      () => console.log('complete')
    ); this.socket.next(value);  Its showing error  in console: ERROR SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
    RxJS 3
    Angular 8

Comment: () => console.log('complete') this is getting executed, but not he part where I am displaying msg

Answer (score 1):

actually in AngularCli applications you can define a service like this and start to connecting into Web socket server

```
 // websocket.servoce.ts
 import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
 import { webSocket } from "rxjs/webSocket";


 @Injectable()
 export class WebsocketService {

   // ha ha look at the host address
   private subject = webSocket("ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx ;)/ws/");
   // use pipe to push data into components
   constructor() {
     console.log("websocket service initialization");
   }

   subscribe() {
     this.subject.subscribe(
       msg => {
         console.log(msg);
         // use angular data pipe to push data into components that is subscribed on pipe
       },
       err => {
         console.log(err);
       }
      )
   }

 }
```

take care thanks for using this service

Answer (score 0):

I believe RxJs sockets expect the payload to be a valid json, are you sending a string or?

Comment: I am sending a string, but at server side am getting the data properly and its getting processed properly and also sending the response of browser. Only thing is response is not getting captured in message variable;